# Getting data from firestore after retrieving collection

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a field within one of my collections that is a reference. I want to receive the data E.g.

```
 var eventsRef = firebase.firestore().collection('events').get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
          var {stringVar1, stringVar2, user} = doc.data()
        }
      })
    })
```

and then take user (the reference) and get its values. Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to act on this.

I tried to do things like user.data() or user.value but I have no idea how to actually retrieve the data that is stored at the reference that -should- be returned by user. Currently user is just a huge output by the response from firebase that starts like this:

Docum

```
entReference {
  "_firestoreClient": FirestoreClient {
    "asyncQueue": AsyncQueue {
      "delayedOperations": Array [],
      "operationInProgress": false,
      "tail": Promise {
        "_40": 0,
        "_55": Promise {
          "_40": 0,
          "_55": undefined,
          "_65": 1,
          "_72": null,
        },
        "_65": 3,
        "_72": null,
      },
    },
    "clientId": "NzKmEZBlNF6FhjgTfoia",
    "credentials": FirebaseCredentialsProvider {
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, if the `user` field in the document is a reference type field, then when fetched, it will appear as a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) type object.  You will have to fetch it with [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get).  (DocumentReference objects are not automatically followed, as that may incur more reads than anticipated, or even result in an infinite loop.)

Comment: Doug... you're a SAINT. Thank you, this was beyond key!  For future peeps: const { stringVar1, stringVar2, user } = doc.data();
      const userData = user.get().then(data => {
        console.log('userdata', data.data())
      })